# How to setup opendaylight contoller cluster over cassandra

Tags: cassandra, opendaylight

I have a Cassandra cluster running and now I want to set up a cluster of opendaylight controller over it.
The wiki page just mentions that I need to point the opendaylight to the cassandra cluster but I am unable to figure out how.

Please provide some details about it.

Comment: Copied from @MKL answer.  Might try posting here: https://ask.opendaylight.org/questions/. Pretty fast response time from the ODL community.

Answer (score 1):

There is an updated  wiki page  about how  to setup clustering  at    https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/Running_and_testing_an_OpenDaylight_Cluster.

You  will need to  use the karaf  distribution and the helium release.

http://www.opendaylight.org/software